# Correct or most efficient way to retrieve integer values from unsigned zero filled integer columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've encountered many different ways of retrieving integer values from zero filled columns, and some give the appearance of costing more than others. As having to retrieve integer values from zero filled columns in my database does occur from time to time, I want to know how best to retrieve them.

Throughout the years I have used/seen statements similar to the ones below:

```
SET @zerofillExample = '000022';

SELECT CAST(@zerofillExample AS unsigned);
SELECT @zerofillExample+0;
SELECT @zerofillExample*1;
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM @zerofillExample);
```

If there is no performance difference in the different ways of casting zero filled columns, is there some standard I am unaware of?

Update, for clarity:

- I know how to select integer values from zero filled columns.
- I am looking for the most efficient way or standard when retrieving integer values
- Some reasons where we cast it as an integer:

  - Some legacy tables use zero fill for their keys, and when manipulating/working with the data either in PHP or JS, `'0000001'!==1`. I am well aware that having different column definitions is a no-no, but that is not the focus of the question.

Comment: As far as I know, zerofill only affects display in direct queries (such as through sql command) and perhaps some tools. Normal queries in client code just get normal integer values.  _...unless you're talking about char or varchar fields holding numeric values._

Comment: You are trying to get `22` from `'000022'` right? Try something like `SELECT '000022' >> 0`  here are some more [examples](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/62xAt69a1SbGyqRT1p7dKr/0) .. This works because off MySQL's auto casting i would not use/trust this in other database systems without testing.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, that is the result I'm aiming for, but what I am asking for is "what is the best way to obtain the integer value" (and nice, I was not aware of `<<` or `>>`)

Comment: Not sure how much `<<` and `>>`, will gain performance over using `*`, `/`, `+` and `-` to auto typecast most likely nothing in SQL.  But iam pretty sure the operator usage is (more) cheaper then using a SQL function looking into the CPU time/cycles needed.. lets see if i can proof that give me a moment.

Comment: @RaymondNijland very insightful, thank you for that. If there is no known community standard for casting zero filled columns, you may post your response above as an answer.

Comment: Take a look into [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340e01/651) the operator one with `<<` most of the time executes faster than the `CAST(..)` function like i predected p.s don't look at the green bar timings look at the results for `SHOW PROFILES` and `SHOW PROFILE CPU FOR QUERY <number>` .. But it's really a micro optimisation generally when it's a micro optimisation you are beter off which makes more sense to use like the `CAST(..)` and `TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM @zerofillExample)` over the bit-twidding ones...

Comment: "If there is no known community standard for casting zero filled columns," Iam pretty sure `ZEROFILL` is a MySQL/MariaDB only feature so there most likely will not be a SQL standard about it... In other database systems you need to simulate/emulate that with some string functions and a view or virtual/generated columns

Comment: Noted, will remove SQL tag as this is a MySQL/MariaDB specific question then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Rule of Thumb:  Ordinary expressions (all 4 of your examples) play an insignificant part in the performance of a query.

Note, further, that *no* expression is really needed:

```
mysql> SELECT '000022' + 1;
+--------------+
| '000022' + 1 |
+--------------+
|           23 |
+--------------+
```

That is, a string with all digits can be used as a number without any conversion, not even to deal with leading zeros.

Have you ever seen `INT(6)`?  Do you know what the `(6)` means?  Nothing.

That is, unless you have `INT(6) ZEROFILL`.  Now, if you `INSERT` `22` into such a column, then display it, you get `000022`.  The *value* is simply `22`; the *display* has leading zeros.

When you say `ZEROFILL`, you are asking for leading zeros.  You don't need to do anything to get the numeric value.  However, if you must _display_it without the leading zeros, then you need any of your kludges.  I prefer a 5th:

```
SELECT 0+@zerofillExample;
```

The `0+...` is a kludge I have seen in some languages for converting a string to a number.  Although you are really starting with a number, this still gives the reader that something fishy is going on.

Using `BENCHMARK()` --

```
SELECT BENCHMARK(1e7, CAST(@zerofillExample AS unsigned));
```

comes back in about 0.45s (on my laptop).  Ditto for your other 3 cases.  However, I don't trust this because `@zerofillExample` is a string, not `INT ZEROFILL`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, although I see that my question should've provided you with more information. Please see my latest update at the bottom of the question. I'm aware it is still a kludge, but for my use case `0+...` does read better than the alternatives

Comment: Selecting as the correct answer as the performance difference is negligible unless micro-optimization is a concern. And there does not appear to be a community standard or preferred way for this specific use case.

Comment: "Community standard" -- I have used `ZEROFILL` perhaps 3 times out of perhaps 10K columns I have defined.  There are 550K [mysql] questions, but only 569 mention `ZEROFILL`.  I suspect your question is more like 1 in 10K.  As for converting a string to an integer, it 'just works', or just screws up, depending on user expectations.